# magento1.9.1 is there any way to make it work with php7.4.4 on xampp 3.2.4

Tags: php, magento, mcrypt, magento-1.9.1

PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded.

could you please help to solve this issue i tried to install mcrypt manually but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the mcrypt to the php.ini pointing to the installation folder.

Comment: yes i install the mcrypt to php files and i added extension=php_mcrypt to php.ini but it still not working , could you please tell me the right solution

Comment: Yes! You need to provide the correct path of the extension in the php ini. Verify where is installed in he terminal, add the full path or the mcrypt to the .ini, restart your server